# Accessing Win32 CreateEvent/SetEvent from WSH or other native Windows program

Tags: windows, winapi, wsh

I need to interface with a program suite that uses named.  Win32 Events (eg, `CreateEvent()` API) to communicate between running processes.

I'm able to do this with some very simple C code

```
 h = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, argv[1]);
 if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) SetEvent(h);
```

However, due to policy issues, I can't install custom binaries on production machines!

Is there a way to do this with Windows Scripting Host?

I could possibly get signed binaries added to the production environment - so other scripting language might be viable.  Recommendations are welcome.

Comment: CreateEvent() returns NULL, not INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, if it fails.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a Win32 event for normal eventing purposes, you could use PowerShell.  This will give you access to the .Net framework.  This will allow you to indirectly access the API by using a managed event class such as ManualResetEvent.  This is just a thin wrapper on top of the normal CreateEvent APIs.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't install custom binaries on production machines!
>   ...
>   I could possibly get signed binaries added to the production environment

Sign your own binaries.

Whoever instituted such a policy that allows you to run arbitrary WSH programs but not binaries should pay for your code-signing cert.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a PyWin32 library that allows you to use Windows API functions, including CreateEvent/SetEvent.

In general (and with different level of convenience), you could use any language that allows defining and invoking external functions (from kernel32.dll in this case).