# Trigger global event from wsf script

Tags: windows, winapi, wsh

I have a Windows service that is using WaitForMultipleObjectsEx with a global event.

Is there a way for me to trigger this event from a windows scripting host file - JScript or VB script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing Win32 CreateEvent/SetEvent from WSH or other native Windows program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858816/accessing-win32-createevent-setevent-from-wsh-or-other-native-windows-program)

Comment: That appears to be a duplicate - but it does not seem to have an accepted answer.

Comment: Yes that's true, but the point of duplicates is to keep all of the answers in one place. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) for an explanation of the reasoning.

Comment: Is there a way to resurrect the original question to say that people are still asking it - old questions don't seem to get many answers.

Comment: Also, the original question includes "or other native windows program." and that is what all of the answers chose to look at - instead of my more specific question.

Comment: Well this question and our conversation will generate some interest, but if you have sufficient rep you can [offer a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on the original question to try to get some more responses. However, if you feel that your question really *is* different, maybe edit it to make that clear - I'll happily withdraw my close vote :-)